# Broken Excel Interop COM assembly after installing/removing 2013 beta release

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop, office-2013

I have recently installed Microsoft Office 2013 beta release while having 2007 already installed. When I opened a COM based Excel interop application under Visual Studio 2008, I noticed a few warnings I didn't have before. I tried to start compile the application and it still worked, but when I tried to use the feature that uses the Excel interop, I received an error.

I immediately uninstalled Office 2013 after that, but the error stayed. I messed around in the C:\Windows\assembly folder and still didn't manage to fix it.

After that, I went ahead and uninstalled / reinstalled Office 2007. Still no luck. I uninstalled Office 2007 again, deleted all the assemblies regarding interop (including the Policy ones), reinstalled Office 2007. Still nothing.

I tried installing the PrimaryInteropAssembly. Also nothing.

I'm out of options... What can I do?

The application can still compile and will still work on other machines too. It's really just my machine that cannot run it anymore.

*This might be off topic, I'm not sure which Stack Exchange this kind of things will fit into, but since it's related to programming without being actual code, I gave it a shot here. I think the people competent in this domain resides more in SO over SF*

**The warning in VS**

Could not determine the dependencies of the COM reference "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel". Erreur lors du chargement de la bibliothèque/DLL du type. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

(French part translation: "Error loading library / DLL type.")

**The error when running the application on the developpement machine**

[image]

Comment: What is the error?!!  I can't believe people complain about errors without posting the actual error!!!!

Comment: Uninstall, run a registry cleaner, then re-install..

Comment: Uninstall what? Office? VS? Both? What registry cleaner?

Comment: Installing betas on production machines is a Really Bad Idea.  Particularly the uninstaller is the last thing they get solid.  Right now the registry is corrupted, it isn't clear why re-installing 2007 doesn't fix the problem.  It *may* be a file that the 2013 uninstaller forgets to remove so that the 2007 installer doesn't replace it.

Comment: I know it was. We all learn by mistakes, unfortunatly. But what do you suggest to fix it? Reinstalling the machine is out of the options :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answered on [Microsoft MSDN comunity forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/exceldev/thread/dd052f27-20d6-4b6b-9d8b-fe4fd9c6b9fc). There is one registery key to remove.

Everything went back to normal after that.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs even with the currently released Office 2013 from MSDN; and the removal of the registry entry still fixes it.

Comment: Did not fix similar issue for me.